# How to make a slicer with multiple column names as options

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating some reports in Power BI and I have a table which looks as follows:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Options | Has Option1 | Has Option2 | Has Option3 | Has Option4 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   1;2   |      Y      |      Y      |      N      |      N      |
|  2;3;4  |      N      |      Y      |      Y      |      Y      |
|    4    |      N      |      N      |      N      |      Y      |
|   2;3   |      N      |      Y      |      Y      |      N      |
```

I would like to create a slicer that would look something like this:

```
[] Has Option1
[] Has Option2
[] Has Option3
[] Has Option4
```

Such that whichever options are selected in the slicer, only data would appear in the visuals that have "Y" in the corresponding "Has OptionX" column.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think your pattern look similar to [this one](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-or-conditions-between-slicers-in-dax/)

Comment: I don't think this pattern is relevant to the question. It describes measures, while the OP is looking to create a slicer.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I tried to make that solution work, but could not figure out how it applies to my problem. If anyone has any other ideas please let me know.